# How to add greek character in matlab comment?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

Can someone tell me how to add greek character in matlab comment? eg. micron, alpha etc
When I publish the m file in PDF, #'\mu' (comment) does not show the greek character. How can this be fixed?
%[\mu] does not work

Comment: whatever is written after % sign is comment in matlab

Answer (score 1):

One option that works for me is to use [LaTeX equations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btj5jsh-1).

You can publish LaTeX by preceding the LaTeX portion of file with `%%`:

```
% Regular comment..

%%
% This is an equation: $x^2+e^{\pi i}$. It is 
% inline with the text.
% This is a $\mu$
%

% Regular comment..
```

When you publish this you will see that `% Regular comments` indeed appear as regular comments and the LaTeX part (i.e. consecutive comment blocks after `%%` until the break) appears as LaTeX.

This doesn't seem to work directly for your program example i.e. you can't invoke LaTeX in the same line as the program. You can put your comment in a separate line like this

```
%% 
% $\mu$ 
z = linspace(-1,0.5,500);
```

or for instance create variable lists for blocks of code just for the publishing part.

Answer (score 0):

I usually specify the interpreter. For example:

```
text(X,Y,'$\mu$','interpreter','latex')

xlabel('$\mu$','interpreter','latex')
```

Comment: I asked how to specify greek characters in MATLAB comment. It works otherwise but how to display greek character in comment? eg. %[\mu]

Comment: when i publish pdf file in mathwork, in my comment #[microns], I want to see greek symbol instead. What should I specify in my editor/code, so that after publishing I get to see the greek character in pdf file.

Comment: See- this is my code in editor: z = linspace(-1,0.5,500); % ['\mu']          and this is what I get in pdf: z = linspace(-1,0.5,500); % ['\mu']     It is not decoding mu to its greek character.